# Dating equivalent of 'spouse'

Tags: word-choice, hypernyms, gender-neutral

I want to ask someone, "Describe the perfect girlfriend/boyfriend" but I don't want to be so hetero-normative. So I'm looking for **a simple gender-neutral/gender-inclusive equivalent for *boyfriend*/*girlfriend***, like 'spouse' is for *wife*/*husband*.

I can only think of:

- *Significant Other* (SO)
- *Partner* (not the best for just dating, though)

Those both feel kind of stiff. Are there any others that I'm not aware of, possibly more casual? Particularly ones that would be easy to explain to non-native English speakers?

Comment: What wrong with: Describe your best boy/girlfriend? A man or woman can have either a boyfriend or a girlfriend, and sometimes both. But a genderless noun that might work is *companion*. Although it's not very romantic.

Comment: I want that romantic notion. Your *best friend* is often not the person you're romantically involved with.

Comment: A boyfriend and a girlfriend are completely different from a best friend. *Companion* is genderless, but it lacks the sexual, romantic connotations that the former have, and it can mean a travel companion as well as a partner. For talking about someone whom you go out with and have deep romantic feelings for, it's GF and BF (for me).

Comment: Lover and sweetheart, it appears to me, are the simplest and commonly recognized gender-neutral/gender-inclusive equivalent for a date/BF/GF .

Comment: I think it depends on whether you want to hear about the expected _role_ they should have or about what person they are; as in the person you should be with as opposed the _person you want to be with, now_ and (maybe) tomorrow. _Person_ is the neutral way to address the person imho.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ordan & Wintner in their [study](http://cs.haifa.ac.il/~shuly/publications/gender.pdf)<sup>1</sup> on representing natural gender have observed that there seems to be no neutral hypernym for the pair *boyfriend/girlfriend.*

> **MF** This class includes nouns which have distinct masculine and feminine forms, but no gender neutral one.
>   Examples:
>   boyfriend/girlfriend, lord/lady, male/female, prince/princess, uncle/aunt.
>   17 nouns are in this class.

<sup>1</sup> Src: (pdf: 86kB) <sup>Noam Ordan and Shuly Wintner, *Representing natural gender in multilingual lexical databases*, Dept Comp Sc, Univ of Haifa, p3., p7.</sup>

Comment: ... Noam dropper.

Answer (score 4):

There is ***squeeze*** in slang. Though, it is used as a sexual partner too. I don't know if there is much difference nowadays.

There is also ***main squeeze*** but it has somewhat a stronger sense than *squeeze* and you can call your spouse as your *main squeeze* too.

> Main squeeze "most important person" is attested from 1896; meaning "one's sweetheart, lover" is attested by 1980. [[Etymonline]](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=squeeze)

There is ***lover*** and ***sweetheart*** but they are usually used for someone more intimate and more suitable to use in longer relationships.

There is ***date*** but it is usually used for a companion of a single occasion.

Let's go with ***valentine***.

Comment: The distributions of _though_ and _however_ are not identical.

Answer (score 0):

*Date* can be used to mean the person you are dating [http://www.oxforddictionaries.com...?](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/date)

"Describe the perfect date" is confusing though, as it is likely to be interpreted as "Describe what would happen on your perfect date" rather than "Describe the person who would be your perfect date."

So how about "Describe the person who would be your perfect date." or perhaps better still "What sort of person would be your perfect date?"

Comment: Every time I hear that, all I can think of is "April 21st. It's not too warm and not too cold. All you need is a light jacket." Or however the quote goes... XD

Answer (score 0):

Lover, (Life) Partner, SO (significant other), Bae

Comment: Please add references for each word/phrase.